# Can not boot WIN 10 anymore

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I run Ubuntu 14 and Windows 10 and bootloader Grub.
Everything was fine until there was a major Windows update. It took very long to download. I had to kill a user in Windows because I could not get the task manager loaded anymore. Under the admin account the update completed. 
I can start Ubuntu. When I choose Windows in the bootloader menu, I get an error:
error: no such device: 0A181xxxxx
Setting partition type to 0x7

Press any key to continue...

next screen is:
An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any devices that don't 
contain an operating system.
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart.

From Ubuntu I can access my C: drive (SSD) and my old C: drive (Sata).

What can I do best now?

I do not have startup rescue things. I do have a Veeam backup. 
I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: download a windows install disk and run the bootrec commands but DO NOT run the bootrec mbr command or you will have to reinstall grub

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Windows update did change your energy settings configuration,
or the update somehow "changed"  something within the EFI boot partition.

**First attempt** :

Boot into BIOS - select Ubuntu in UEFI settings to be the default OS to boot.

When everything is fine now you're done - if not ...

**Second attempt** :

Boot into Windows - disable hibernation and Fast Boot.

To disable hibernation open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** (the old version - not the modern design),
select the **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and **uncheck Fast Boot**.

After having done this **shutdown** the machine **completely** - do **NOT reboot** !

When everything is fine now you're done - if not ...

**Third attempt** :

**Reinstall the GRUB boot loader** to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.
**Boot from the Ubuntu installation media** - open a terminal and execute:

```
    sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
    sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
    for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
    sudo chroot /mnt
    grub-install /dev/sd*
    update-grub
```

Note:

`sd*` = disk | `sd**` = efi partition | `sd***` = system partition

To identify the partition numbers use **GParted** - it is included in the Ubuntu installation media.
Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu in UEFI settings to be the default operating system to boot.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. 1St attempt; What is UEFI settings? I checked the BIOS but can not find anything simular? 2nd attempt; Fastboot is already disabled in the BIOS. How do I disable Hybernate? I can not startup Windows.

Comment: @Cees : Boot from Windows install media - on 'Install now' screen select 'Repair your computer' - choose 'Command prompt' and execute : 1.) bootrec.exe /fixboot  2.)  bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd | After this follow exactly the instructions given in the answer - start a with the second attempt and then continue with the third attempt ! UEFI is the successor of BIOS ... please change the settings in BIOS (UEFI) as described. :)

Comment: SUCCES!!! No Win10 CD it was an upgrade. I used Win 7 CD. The second screen gave me the option for repair. this gave a me question: "Windows found problems with your computer's startup options. Do you want to apply repairs and restart your computer?" I pressed ok, fingers crossed. It restarted but with no result.  One more time from Win 7 CD. I choose repair again and got another screen: System recovery options. I choose "Use recovery tools that can help fix problems starting Windows. Select an operating system to repair." My OS was listed and the problem was fixed!! YES, thank you so much.

Comment: I still get the first screen "error: no such device: 0A181xxxxx Setting partition type to 0x7". But when I choose enter, it boots Win10. Is there a way to get rid of this message?